# Bound sum of series of squares over exponentials

Tags: number-theory, analysis

Can we upper bound $$\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{i^2(\ln K)^2}{K^{10i}}$$
by a universal constant if we choose $K>0$  large enough?

Comment: @SL_MathGuy There should be no - in the denominator. I just removed it.

Comment: So, can this upper bound depend upon $K$? or you're seeking an u.b which is independent from $K$?

Comment: @SL_MathGuy A bound independentof $K$ is good enough. i just found it is $o(1)$ as $K$ tends to infinity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $S\triangleq \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{i^2(\ln K)^2}{K^{10i}}=(\ln K)^2\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}i^2K^{-10i}.$
\begin{align}
\frac{1-K^{-10}}{(\ln K)^2}S&= \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}i^2K^{-10i}-\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}i^2K^{-10(i+1)}\\
&=K^{-10}+\sum_{i=2}^{\infty}i^2K^{-10i}-(i-1)^2K^{-10i}\\
&=K^{-10}+\sum_{i=2}^{\infty}(2i-1)K^{-10i}.
\end{align}
Now let $T\triangleq\sum_{i=2}^{\infty}(2i-1)K^{-10i}$.
\begin{align}
(1-K^{-10})T&= \sum_{i=2}^{\infty}(2i-1)K^{-10i}-\sum_{i=2}^{\infty}(2i-1)K^{-10(i+1)}\\
&=3K^{-20}+\sum_{i=3}^{\infty}(2i-1)K^{-10i}-(2(i-1)-1)K^{-10i}\\
&=3K^{-20}+\sum_{i=3}^{\infty}2K^{-10i}=3K^{-20}+2\frac{K^{-30}}{1-K^{-10}},
\end{align}
assuming $K>1$.
Thus, we have
\begin{align}
S&=\frac{(\ln K)^2}{1-K^{-10}}\left[K^{-10}+\frac{1}{1-K^{-10}}\left(3K^{-20}+2\frac{K^{-30}}{1-K^{-10}}\right)\right]\\
&=(\ln K)^2\left[\frac{K^{-10}}{1-K^{-10}}+\frac{3K^{-20}}{(1-K^{-10})^{2}}+2\frac{K^{-30}}{(1-K^{-10})^3}\right]\\
&=(\ln K)^2\frac{K^{-10}(1+K^{-10})}{(1-K^{-10})^3}.
\end{align}
Since $S$ is a decresing function of $K$, $S(K)\leq S(K_0),$ for all $K\geq K_0>1$.

Answer (score 1):

Choose any $K \geq 2$. Then, $K^n \geq (\ln K)^2$ for each $n$ (can be proved by induction). Hence, $$K^ {10n}= K^{9n}K^n \geq 2^{9n} (\ln K)^2 \geq 2^n (ln K)^2$$

Therefore, $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{n^2}{K^ {10n}} \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{n^2}{2^n (ln K)^2}= \dfrac{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{n^2}{2^n}}{(\ln K)^2} $$.

What can you say about the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{n^2}{2^n}$? This converges to 6!! (To prove this, you could use the result $\sum x^n = \frac{x}{1-x}$, when $|x|<1$)

Hence for any $K \geq 2$, the series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{n^2 (\ln K)^2}{K^ {10n}} \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{n^2}{2^n} = 6$$.

Obviously, this upper bound is crude and can be improved.

Answer (score 1):

*Similar to @Geethu Joseph's answer.*

$$S(K)=\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{i^2 \log^2(K)}{K^{10i}}=\log^2(K)\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{i^2 }{(K^{10})^i}$$ Let $x=\frac 1 {K^{10}}$ to face
$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty i^2 x^i=\sum_{i=1}^\infty (i(i-1)+i) x^i=x^2\sum_{i=1}^\infty i(i-1) x^{i-2}+x\sum_{i=1}^\infty i x^{i-1}$$that is to say
$$x^2 \left(\sum_{i=1}^\infty  x^{i} \right)''+x \left(\sum_{i=1}^\infty  x^{i} \right)'=-\frac{x (x+1)}{(x-1)^3}$$

Back to $K$
$$S(K)=\frac{K^{10} \left(K^{10}+1\right)}{\left(K^{10}-1\right)^3} \log^2(K)=\frac 1 {100}\frac{K^{10} \left(K^{10}+1\right)}{\left(K^{10}-1\right)^3} \log^2(K^{10})$$

Now, we can use that, if for any $x$, $\log(x) \leq x^{\frac{1}{e}}$ making
$$S(K)  \leq \frac 1 {100}\frac{K^{10} \left(K^{10}+1\right)}{\left(K^{10}-1\right)^3} \exp\left({K^{\frac {20} e}}\right)$$